# problems with publishing a asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, publish

I have a asp.net web project, in order to get it up in the air, i do publish to the project.

Till today that worked fine, but today when i do publish it only uploads some of my files, stops after about 5 folders, but still gives me a success message saying every thing is up.

and then aviosly, when i go to that link i get a error:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

When i check in the our ftp site i see only some of the files...

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: sounds like it has less to do with .Net and more to do with your FTP or VS. try delete/renaming the files and republishing

Comment: There may be some transmission issues. Have you given it a second try?

Comment: its impossible to rename all my files, but i did delete every thing, and still its starts from the top get down to 5 folders and stops...

Comment: Perhaps instead of using publish, you should try another ftp client.

Comment: Another option is to publish everything locally and then copy compiled site to the necessary ftp location manually. That way if the problem is in FTP, you will see exactly what it is.

Comment: @ Andrei -  Thank you!! I did as you said, and i really got it up, what could be the problem was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record.

For now i got around the problem with Andrei comment:

Another option is to publish everything locally and then copy compiled site to the necessary ftp location manually. That way if the problem is in FTP, you will see exactly what it is.

And it worked

Comment: I always publish to a local folder. The ftp uploader of VS is abysmally slow. I use Filezilla with 10 concurrent uploads (I wish it  supported 100).